# How do I add products to the page.phtml?

Tags: magento2, factory

I have an array with the product ID in my block, how do I get the product list on the page like this:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

the easiest way is to output your collection using `foreach`
 in the .phtml file. Also, you can widget functionality.

Answer (score 0):

1. **Native Way**

   For this you simply have to add a **widget** in your home page, in this widget you select a `Catalog Products List` type then you select the category that you want to display these products, you insert then save. [Mageplaza tuto here.](https://www.mageplaza.com/kb/magento-2-how-insert-products-homepage.html)
2. **Custom Way**

   If you have some custom block and you want absolutely display these products, instead to load the `productId`, load a `categoryId` then you loop the products.

**Don't** forget to clean the cache for the both methods.